# Swapping <div> while retaining its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I am trying to swap two DIVs in a [jQuery-based vertical splitter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311334/jQuery-Splitter), each side contains a website, while retaining the state inside the page. I can't attach the splitter here because it requires an off-line plugin library, but I don't think it matter much for the purpose of this question. Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">swap</button>

  <div id="MySplitter">
    <div class="first">
    <p>A</p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLhlCwhENzc/"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
    <p>B</p><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var tempContent = $("div.first").html();
      $("div.first").empty().html($("div.second").html());
      $("div.second").empty().html(tempContent);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Supposed a user is playing a youtube video in iframe A. When the user click the "swap" button, I wish to swap the two iframe without reloading the youtube video. While my code is able to swap the two div, it always refresh the page and reload the video. I haven't been able to figure out how to resolve this issue. Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use detach, and then re-attach.

I've also added container div's to detach into.

Using IFrame inside a snippet causes issues, so for pretend I've used INPUT's, so for example if you type something into one, and then flip.  You will see you text does not clear, proving it's not re-loading into the DOM, but just moving it.

Update:

Ok, looks like moving iFrames, because of the detach/attach does indeed cause iFrame refresh.  So the best option is not to move within the DOM, this version is using flexbox to move the IFrame's.  You could I suppose use absolute positioning, floats etc.

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('#MySplitter').toggleClass('flip');
}

$('button').click(myFunction);
```

```css
#MySplitter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#MySplitter.flip {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.frame2 {
  background-color: red;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button>swap</button>

  <div id="MySplitter">
    <div class="content">
      <iframe src="."></iframe>   
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <iframe class="frame2" src="."></iframe>   
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Keith. I tried your implementation, it seems fine in snippet, it turns out moving any <div> containing an iframe object within the DOM tree always result in the refresh of iframe contents.I saw that "adoptNode" is supposed to solve this issue, but it doesn't work.

   <div>
  <iframe id="test1" src="AA.html"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div>
  <iframe id="test2" src="BB.html"></iframe>
   </div>

 function myFunction(){
  var x = document.adoptNode(document.getElementById("test1"));
  document.getElementById("test2").appendChild(x);
 }

Comment: Looks like indeed moving iFrame's causes refresh.  But if you move things  without moving inside the DOM, then it's OK.. Just done a modification to use Flexbox that seems to work ok.  Updated my snippet.